# Avoid accessing specific products based on WooCommerce geolocated country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, product

I the code below, I am able to hide specific products for a specific country using WooCommerce `WC_Geolocation` Class:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'bbloomer_hide_product_if_country_new', 9999, 2 );
function bbloomer_hide_product_if_country_new( $q, $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;
    $location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
    $hide_products = array( 17550, 32 );   
    $country = $location['country'];   
    if ( $country === "US" ) {
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', $hide_products );
    } 
}
```

The code works fine and hides the products based on the geolocated country in shop / category and search results on the front-end.

But the products are still visible if someone uses a direct link. How to avoid customers accessing directly specific single product pages too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all your code with the following:

```
// Conditional custom function: check for geolocated countries (array)
function is_targeted_geo_country( $countries ) {
    $location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
    return in_array( $location['country'], $countries );
}

// Hide specific products from catalog
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_product_for_geo_countries', 9999, 2 );
function hide_product_for_geo_countries( $q, $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    $product_ids = array( 17550, 32 );  // Here set the product to hide  
  
    if ( is_targeted_geo_country( array('US') ) ) {
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', $hide_products );
    } 
}

// Avoid accessing specific products, redirecting to shop
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_shop_products_for_geo_countries' );
function redirect_to_shop_products_for_geo_countries() {
    $product_ids = array( 17550, 32 );  // Here set the products to hide  
  
    if ( is_targeted_geo_country( array('US') ) && in_array( get_the_ID(), $product_ids ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
        exit();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sir third part of the code is not working, it says redirects too many times.